# Number guessing game keeps repeating same questions and guesses incorrectly

Tags: java, loops, search, while-loop, binary-search

If you run the the game you can see that certain numbers the game cannot guess correctly. For example if your number is 13 the game will loop two times too many and will also guess your number as 12 instead of 13. I think this is an issue with the counting but I've tried tracing the loops repeatedly but cannot find the error. I think the issue mainly lies within my while loop.

```
//import statements
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numbers
{

   public static void binarySearch()
   {
    int position=0;
    String answer;
    int upper_BOUND=100;
    int lower_BOUND=0;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);


     while( (lower_BOUND <= upper_BOUND))
     {
        position = (lower_BOUND + upper_BOUND) / 2;
        System.out.println("Is your value greater than " + position + "?");
        answer=input.next();
        if((upper_BOUND-lower_BOUND<=1))
        {
            break;
        }
         if (answer.equals("no"))             // If the number is > key, ..
         {                                              // decrease position by one.
              upper_BOUND = position --;
         }
         if(answer.equals("yes"))
         {
              lower_BOUND = position ++;    // Else, increase position by one.
         }



     }


           System.out.println("Is your number " + position + "?");
           String answer2=input.next();
           System.out.println(position+" is the answer.\n Thank you for playing the guessing game.");

     //else
         // System.out.println("Bruh pick a number from 1 to 100 ");
  }

}
```

......
tester class

```
public class NumberGuesser
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[ ] num = new int [100];
        // Fill array
        for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
             num[i]=i;
        //The search method
        Numbers.binarySearch();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the question.?

Comment: you created array in NumberGuesser class but you are not using anywhere :D then where you are searching??

Answer (score 0):

Your issue should be with the increment that you do in "lower_BOUND = position ++; " here what happens is when you increment the position value, the "++" first increments and then assigns the value to position variable. The lowerbound is not actually assigned the incremented value of position but old value of positon. So please make a change to "lower_BOUND =  ++ position ; "

Like below

```
 if(answer.equals("yes"))
         {
              lower_BOUND =  ++ position ;    // Else, increase position by one.
         }
```

And also my suggestion is to check your " if((upper_BOUND-lower_BOUND <= 1))" condition. I guess the condition should be like this  "  if((upper_BOUND-lower_BOUND == 0)) "

And please remove unused code in your "NumberGuesser" class, this will confuse people who are trying to answer your question.